# How to display customer name after login into site in magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi Can anyone tell me how to display customer name after login into the site in magento.

As of now instead of customer name it is displaying as DROPDOWN. Can anyone check this and solve this it will be very helpful for me.As i am new to magento

app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\header.php(code from this file).

```
 public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()));
        } else {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
        }
    }

    return $this->_data['welcome'];
}
```

This is the code from where it is getting as 'DROPDOWN' but not getting how to get the name and display the customer name instead of dropdown.

```
<div data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle md-ink">
<span class="fa fa-cog hidden-sm hidden-lg hidden-md"></span>
<span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $this->__('Dropdown') ?>
<span class="caret"></span></span>                                                          
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if any customer is logged in or not

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    //Load the customer's data

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $customer->getPrefix();
    $customer->getName(); // Full Name
    $customer->getFirstname(); // First Name
    $customer->getMiddlename(); // Middle Name
    $customer->getLastname(); // Last Name
    $customer->getSuffix();

    // All other customer data
    $customer->getWebsiteId(); // ID
    $customer->getEntityId(); // ID
    $customer->getEntityTypeId(); // ID
    $customer->getAttributeSetId(); // ID
    $customer->getEmail();
    $customer->getGroupId(); // ID
    $customer->getStoreId(); // ID
    $customer->getCreatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+01:00
    $customer->getUpdatedAt(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    $customer->getIsActive(); // 1
    $customer->getDisableAutoGroupChange();
    $customer->getTaxvat();
    $customer->getPasswordHash();
    $customer->getCreatedIn(); // Admin
    $customer->getGender(); // ID
    $customer->getDefaultBilling(); // ID
    $customer->getDefaultShipping(); // ID
    $customer->getDob(); // yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    $customer->getTaxClassId(); // ID
}
```

Comment: Actually it is printing as DROPDOWN from default.phtml can you please check it once instead of dropdown i need to display customer name.

Comment: As i changed the code with the one which you posted but it is displaying as dropdown only

Comment: First of all according to my code your customer should be logged in
see just do one thing 

    return $customer->getFirstname();

call this function in your phtml

$customerName = $this->yourFunctionName();

<?php echo $this->__("$customerName"); ?>

Comment: I am not getting you can you explain it little bitter in my code so that i can understand

Comment: see your header.php code is correct it will return "welcome Customer Name" if your customer logged in . 

it magento default when you logged in it will show the customer name.

but if you want to call it custom you can call this header.php function or you can make your own block and call it in phtml for dropdown you need to remove that code and call the function as i mentioned